# replace values in a data frame with an NA based on the occurrence of NAs in lookup table

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replaces values in a data frame in R with *NA* based on the occurrence of *NAs* in a lookup table like the below example.

```
lookup <- data.frame(date1=c("2018-02-21", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-14"), 
                      date2=c("2018-08-22", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-14", NA), 
                      date3=c("2018-10-03", "2019-01-14", NA, NA), 
                      date4=c("2018-10-31", NA, NA, NA)
                      )

values <- data.frame(val1=c(22.2, 42.1, 38.2, 41.9), 
                      val2=c(23.8, 40.5, 38.5, 39.7), 
                      val3=c(24.2, 39.8, 40.2, NA), 
                      val4=c(27.0,40.1, NA, NA)
                      )

values_new <- data.frame(val1=c(22.2, 42.1, 38.2, 41.9), 
                     val2=c(23.8, 40.5, 38.5, NA), 
                     val3=c(24.2, 39.8, NA, NA), 
                     val4=c(27.0,NA, NA, NA)
                     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
values2 <- values * NA^(is.na(lookup))
```

Or use

```
values[is.na(lookup)] <- NA
```

-checking

```
> identical(values, values_new)
[1] TRUE
```